Why does my Spring Boot server always start on port 8080?
I have a Spring Boot application which should start on port 8090. In my application.yml I set the set these parameter :
spring:
  application:
    name: reactive-user
  server:
    port: 8090
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:h2:mem:///myusers
    username: sa
    password: password
  sql:
    init:
      platform: h2
      mode: always

But when the application start I see this log :
Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'

At the beginning the Spring Initializer generate an application.properties and I rename it in application.yaml. I have only one configuration file.
Is anyone can help me on this issue.

It must be server:port and not spring:server:port

Does this answer your question? How to configure port for a Spring Boot application

Are you using .yaml extension or .yml ? File looks ok to me can you confirm

@Harsh, as others pointed out, that property is not the correct one.

you need to set config like below :
server:
  port: 8090

configuration should start server tag. dont put it under spring tag.
if you want to add context-path then config like below:
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /reactive-user
  port: 8090

